# Will the temperature reading of a thermostat change as a result of direct skin contact?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

If I was to place my hand on a thermostat for an extended period of time, would this eventually result in the temperature reading rising after a period of time - or would the reading not be impacted at all?

Comment: The question is unclear. What is the thermostat reading prior to contact with the skin? What kind of "thermostat" are you talking about?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on a few factors.

Your hand's temperature is supposed to be $37\text{ }^{\circ}\text{C}$, considerable higher than 'usual' room temperature ($\approx 20\text{ }^{\circ}\text{C}$), so that heat MUST flow from hand to thermostat, in accordance with the Laws of Thermodynamics.

However, the 'beating heart' of a thermostat is usually encased in a plastic protective casing that greatly reduces the heat flux from hand to thermocouple.

The latter, from what I've seen, is a spiral bimetal thermocouple. If you could put your hands on it **directly** you would definitely influence its temperature reading. But that's not possible without taking the assembly apart.